# Asigning the href (i.e., route name and route param name) in template based on the value from scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to AngularJs and still learning the things, I'm creating a menu with items that are clickable. When someone clicks on the item it will redirect to a view using the route name provided in the href, the catch here is that my menu will be generates out of the scope from the controller using the ng-repeat. I want to change my href value based on the item value, so that the corresponding view will be loaded based on route, here is my mark up and the controller that populates the scope. Can someone help me what is the best way to do this.

```
 <a data-ng-repeat="c in vm.List | orderBy: 'order'" href="#Categories/{{c.category}}/{{c.name}}" data-ng-show="{{c.count}} >0">




function getHomeConfigsCtrl($http, iService, $routeParams) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.List = [];
    var promise =
        iService.getConfig(ID);
    promise.then(
       function (result) {
           angular.forEach(result.data.menu, function (value, key) {
               vm.List.push(value);
           });
       },
       function (errorPayload) {
           $log.error('failure loading home page config', errorPayload);
       });
};
```

Comment: Use `ng-href` and remove interpolation `{{}}` from ng-show expression, i.e `data-ng-show="c.count"`. If it is one time list do not place orderBy filter on the view, instead just use the filter on the source array in the controller. But what is the issue that you have right now?

Comment: @PSL, thanks for the reply. I don't have any issue with the interpolation, my href is not dependent on that, my href (which points to the route) here in the above example '#Categories', should be changing based on the c.name. Example: if c.name is 'ABC'  i should route the user to 'root1/ABC/:123' else if c.name is 'DEF' i should route the user to 'root2/DEF'.